# React Native could not connect to development server error while running apk installed app on android

Tags: react-native, apk

I have build the apk of my react native app and installed it on android device. But whenever I try to open the app it shows below errors:

[ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhqFn.jpg)

[ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkjXB.jpg)

Any help or suggestion would be well appreciated.

Comment: I assume your app on debug mode. So are you running app via wireless connection or using connected cable?

Comment: How can I turn it to release mode? I am running it by installing the apk version on android so it's wireless.

Comment: You can use `cd android` and then `./gradlew assembleRelease` to make release build. You can also run debug mode wirelessly. See [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device#1-wi-fi-network).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `./gradlew assembleRelease` to generate apk in release mode or `./gradlew bundleRelease` to generate the bundle of the app .aab

for more, you can follow this https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-aab